# will boot command params acpi=off or acpi=noirq ruin my hardware?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, acpi

Dell xps 15z here. Really, really trying to install linux distro to dual boot from.

first goto is bt. cant even get past 'initramfs live media filesystem not found' on usb boot.

next was ubuntu, fedora..may try gentoo

Im learning it is not a distro problem. it is a hardware problem.

with ubuntu i can get boot. i havent tried the install yet, because i need acpi=off to get boot success.

my question is will boot params acpi=off or acpi=noirq burn out my hardware if im driving in the linux distro all day everyday?

Answer (score 6):

[Ubuntu provides a guide for working with this machine](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupport/Machines/Laptops/Dell/XPS/15z). Apparently the *installer* needs `acpi=off`; `acpi=noirq` suffices for standard booting, which simply doesn't use ACPI for irq routing. (Which seems unlikely to matter on a laptop -- if it were a large SMP system, it might matter.)

Comment: thank you for the answer. yes that link is where i found the acpi=off.

thing is, i must have incorrectly identified what is making my fan go full blast...

Comment: +1 Had trouble installing Mint Linux 12 on a Windows 7 laptop. Tried Ubuntu, no luck, then I found this post. Adding the acpi=off option allowed the installer to run successfully.

Comment: @Josh: did `acpi=off` work for the Mint installer or the Ubuntu installer?

Comment: Sorry, should have been more clear. I only tested the option with the Mint installer

Answer (score 0):

There has been a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1586380/has-booting-twice-with-grub-acpi-off-broken-my-monitor) uploaded where there was damage done to a monitor for booting with `acpi=off`. So the answer seems to be **yes, you can damage hardware with `acpi=off`.**