# Has booting twice with GRUB `acpi=off` broken my monitor?

Tags: linux, display, hardware-failure, acpi, ubuntu-20.04

I'm running Ubuntu Fossa 20.04.1 with latest apt updates/upgrades. My monitor is a **Asus VG248QE** 1920x1080 144Hz running on DisplayPort.

First time I booted it up I ran into a problem: After a few hours of using my computer I was running out of SSD memory because `/var/log/kern.log` and `/var/log/syslog` were each 40GB in size. This is because hundreds of lines  were being logged a second like so (copied from a [thread with my same issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1117992/acpi-exception-ae-not-found-while-evaluating-gpe-method-floods-syslog)

```
ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE # Not exact line but similar
Aug 26 17:10:55 mortal kernel: [ 3657.482759] ACPI Error: [PGRT] Namespace lookup failure, AE_NOT_FOUND (20160108/psargs-359)
Aug 26 17:10:55 mortal kernel: [ 3657.482760] ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_GPE._L6F] (Node ffff8810348d56e0), AE_NOT_FOUND (20160108/psparse-542)
```

So I tried the solution from the above thread and it did not work. I then found another thread suggesting I try booting with GRUB option `acpi=off`. This actually fixed my issue.

**First time I booted up like this my monitor was blank during GRUB and after logging in, I had to turn it on and off again for it to show Fossa's Desktop**.

***Second time around it just refused to work altogether, Display port and HDMI.***

I booted into windows and when connecting my monitor my second monitor went haywire, frames being cut as if they were not vsyncing properly. I switched to HDMI and it seemed to work though my graphics card manager alerted me of the following:

> The system has detected a link failure and cannot set the requested resolution and refresh rate. Your display might not support the requested resolution or there may be an issue...

I'm worried about booting back into linux. I've not found any sign/example of `acpi=off` harming hardware unless the BIOS ACPI is disabled.

**Extra Details:**

- I've renabled acpi in linux and the log problem is back
- Linux incorrectly detects the monitor as being a 800x600 (still does not work). I've tried manually setting a newmode with `xrand` and `gtf` but it errors saying something about `incompatible crt`.
- The last few times I booted with `acpi=on` I was also having an issue where the terminal tickrate would blow up, causing the cursor to fly off when pressing an arrow key and write many letters with a single keypress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **yes, the displayPort on the monitor can suffer permanent damages due to setting `acpi=off` in GRUB**. My AMD RX480 DisplayPort Outputs still work though and I managed to use one to connect to my monitor DVI input, which still works.

It's worth mentioning I solved my ACPI issue by installing the latest BIOS Update. The BIOS update mentioned having bettered Kaby/Sky lake cpu microcode, which has been said to be the issue.